# If $g(y) = \int_{A(y)} f(x)\, dx$ and $f(x)$ is smooth, what conditions on $A$ will make $g$ smooth?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives

Suppose that $f: \mathbb{R}^{d} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuously differentiable function.

Suppose that $y \mapsto A(y)$ is a set-valued function that takes values in $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ for $y \in \mathbb{R}^{j}$.

Suppose that $\int_{A(y)} f(x)\, dx$ exists for every $y$.

Define $g(y) = \int_{A(y)} f(x)\, dx$.

What are some general conditions on $y \mapsto A(y)$ that will ensure that $g$ is continuously differentiable in $y$?

Suppose more specifically that $A(y) = 1(h(x,y) \leq 0)$ for some vector-valued function $h$. What conditions on $h$ ensure that $g$ is continuously differentiable in $y$?